# Feedback plugin for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there an alternative to Rails Feedback plugin - https://github.com/jsboulanger/feedback ?
I want something to work with Rails 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try rewritten [version](https://github.com/dohkoos/feedback) for rails 3? Also another [version](https://github.com/dmfrancisco/feedback) here?

Comment: I didn't know about it, thanks. This is more helpful than the DIY answer below. Too bad I was on holidays and forgot about the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use plain old ruby-on-rails programming? You have users, you have content items,
you introduce a new object/table "Feedback" which belongs to user and belongs to content item. If you have several content types, you can use a polymorphic associations.

Now you put the attributes you like in the object (stars, grades, comments, public/private, etc). You put the forms for entering and displaying the feedback into partials and put them everywhere you need them. Later you can add some fancy ajax-stuff.

Even if this may take a little longer, you use the time to master the framework, so I think the time is well invested.

Comment: DIY.. The leap from doing-it-yourself to Uservoice is huge. As an experienced Rubyist I know it takes time to make good solutions, even if they appear simple at first glance. I hoped this was a wheel already invented.

Answer (score 0):

uservoice.com [has a gem](https://github.com/iltempo/uservoice) you can use. it integrates with the user voice feedback system.

Also, [ruby-satisfaction](https://github.com/satisfaction/ruby-satisfaction#readme) is a gem that hooks into the Get Satisfaction API.

Note that GetSatisfaction and UserVoice inspired jsboulanger's feedback plugin.

Comment: Uservoice and GetSatisfaction is definitely not the answer I'm looking for, sorry

Comment: it would be helpful if you gave a bit more description of what you are looking for

Comment: see the bounty text too. I'd like something more light-weight than uservoice and the like. A rails engine would be ideal, to have all data yourself and being able to customize it.